# chart - Find Intersection point xAxis is in DateTime Series | milliSeconds and Y value is Range ( 0 - 100 )

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, equation

Can you please suggest to me how I draw the vertical line on the intersection point
where y meets x at 0 value? xAxis are in Time Series and yAxis are numeric.

[image]

Comment: I've noticed you asked the same question here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=49067 . We work as a single team across all support platforms, so please do not duplicate your question in multiple threads in the future. Your thread will be continued at the Highcharts forum. Reards!

Comment: agree. I am actually looking for a mathematical solution to find the intersection. also, the solution on the high chart is not yet fully working.